# How to save drag and dropped image as .jpg format to database using jquery and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to Jquery. trying to drag and drop image clone. but I am not able to save this drag image to my database using PHP. please someone refer some code.

here is my code:

```
var test = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#working-area .rotatable').live('dblclick', function(event) {
        $(this).remove();   
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .rotatable').draggable({appendTo: "working-area", helper: "clone" });

    $('#working-area .rotatable').live('click', function(event) {
        test = test + 90;
        $(this).rotate({ angle: test ,  appendTo: "#working-area"}).draggable();
    });

    $('#working-area .rotatable').live('mousemove', function(event) {
        $(this).resizable({appendTo: "#working-area"}).parent().draggable();
});
    $( "#working-area" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: "#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .rotatable",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    <!--$( this ).find( "#working-area" ).remove();-->
    $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());

    }
}).mousemove(function(e){

        var xx = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var yy = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

          $('#status2').html("X = "+ xx +', '+"Y = "+ yy);
      });
});
```

Comment: you want to save the image in the db or only a path?

Comment: I want to save that drag and drop image as a .jpeg format. I want to save it first in a folder as well as in database. So, plz refer some code how to solve this problem.....

Answer (score 0):

With "database" I guess you mean that you want to store the image on the server side. So, you need to post your image to the server side. jQuery is an javascript client library and don't have direct access to you database server.

You can do this by an AJAX call or via a basic form post.

Comment: I want to save the image in my db....I'm new in jquery. can you plz refer some code by an Ajax to solve this problem...

Comment: I want to save that drag and drop image as a .jpeg format. I want to save it first in a folder as well as in database. So, plz refer some code how to solve this problem.....